# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Akhil_News_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php:550

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminmenu

Magento newbie here, learning the platform by following a tutorial. I use magento 1.9.3.2. I have looked at all other posts relating this problem and yet it persists. I'm creating a simple menu in admin panel and get the error above. Here's some code:
`app\etc\modules\Akhil_News.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
      <Akhil_News>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Akhil_News>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And **config.xml** in `app\code\local\Akhil\News\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Akhil_News>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Akhil_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <news>
                <class>Akhil_News_Helper</class>
            </news>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Akhil_News</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </news_setup>
            <news_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </news_write>
            <news_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </news_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

The admin html in `app\code\local\Akhil\News\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <news module="akhil_news" >
            <title>News</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <managenews module="akhil_news">
                    <title>Manage News</title>
                    <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_news/adminhtml_news</action>
                </managenews>
            </children>
        </news>
    </menu>
</config>
```

And finally the helper class `app\code\local\Akhil\News\Helper\Data.php`

```
 <?php
    
     class Akhil_News_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
     {
        
     }
?>
```

These files should give me a menu with no functionality in admin panel. However the entire admin is throwing this error. I have looked at other posts and,
1.Compilation is disabled
2.Cleared the cache multiple times
3.Most other posts solutions were closing tags or naming of the class.

If I set in `app\etc\modules\Akhil_News.xml` the module to false, I get a normal page load so I believe the mistakes is in one of the config files but I'm unable to find it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do following ways.

1. Do the caching and indexing one's.
2. Do the "`Compilation`" one's from admin.

NOTE: Before compilation, please take the backup of website.

Comment: I deleted all files and refreshed the indexes and cleared the cache. Then put the files back in and now it's fine. I guess it was the indexing because I didn't refresh it until now?

Comment: Yes some time caching or reindexing create this type of issues.